# feof() doesn´t detect end of file when i'm updating a binary file in C/C++

Tags: c++, file, binaryfiles, feof

I have a binary file with registries of the `Student` struct form.
And I have this code in my `.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student
{
    int id;
    int age;
    char name[50+1];
    int dateOfBirth;
};

bool mustIncrementAge(int dateOfBirth)
{   // a silly function, only for the example.

    return true;
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    FILE* fileStudents;
    fileStudents = fopen("Students.dat", "rb+");

    Student regStudent;
    fread(&regStudent, sizeof(Student), 1, fileStudents);

    while(!feof(fileStudents)) // The cycle never ends. feof() doesn't detect end of file.
    {
        if(mustIncrementAge(regStudent.dateOfBirth))
        {
            regStudent.age++;
            fseek(fileStudents, (-1)*sizeof(Student), SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite(&regStudent, sizeof(Student), 1, fileStudents);
        }

        fread(&regStudent, sizeof(Student), 1, fileStudents);
    }

    fclose(fileStudents);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to update the file, incrementing the ages of Students if they verify the `mustIncrementAge(dateOfBirth)` function (I put it always true).

The problem is that the `while` loop never ends. `feof()` doesn't detect the end of file.

If the file is empty, `feof()` works and the `while` never executes.
But if the file has at least 1 `Student` registry, then it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

I understand that the `feof()` function need a previous read, and that it's that I have done. But it looks like when I write (updating `Student`), the end of file it moves away. That´s is what I don't understand. Why this occurs? If I'm overwriting the registry.

Comment: You are not checking to make sure `fread()` is successful, ie with `ferror()`. But, why use `FILE*` at all in C++ instead of using `std::fstream`?

Comment: `#include <iostream>` makes the code non C, don't tag C.

Comment: The duplicate question is not actually a duplicate. That question relates to checking `feof()` before the 1st read. But this code is clearing reading before checking eof, as it should be. But in any case, the correct way to write this loop is to use `while (fread(...) > 0)` instead, and then use `feof()` and `ferror()` after the loop finishes to find out why it finished.

Comment: Why have you completely overridden the question and lost the edits made by the SO users?

Comment: `fseek()` does not set the EOF bit.

Comment: You should take advantage of the `std::string` type since you are programming in C++.  Char arrays are error prone.

Comment: At least it is not documented to do so, @273K. But that's moot, because the last operation prior to each of the OP's `feof()` calls is an `fread()`, which *does* set the end-of-file indicator if it fails to read any data on account of encountering the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C stdio functions, you have to be careful when you switch back and forth between reading from and writing to the same file.  You need to call a file-positioning function at each switch, except that you may substitute an `fflush()` call when switching from writing to reading, and you don't need to do anything when switching to writing immediately after a read reports EOF.  (C17 7.21.5.3/7)

You do `fseek()` when switching from reading to writing, but in the event that you write, you fail to `fflush()` or reposition the file when switching from writing back to reading.  An `fflush()` immediately after the `fwrite()` seems sensible, but even a nullary position-setting such as `fseek(fileStudents, 0, SEEK_CUR);` should do.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. To see if I understood correctly:
The fflush() is needed when switching from writing back to reading because without it the read occurs before all data was correctly writing. 
t's that correct?

Comment: @Alexis, the `fflush()` or file-positioning function is required *because the specification says it is*. Omitting it leaves the behavior of your program undefined, and the non-termination is a manifestation of that.  It is plausible that if you studied your C implementation, you might find that yes, in your case it was reading back buffered output as if it were fresh input, but even if so, that matters little.